# PDF print to file path VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code I have researched and got to work in one of my workbooks. The idea of the code is to automatically print a sheet to PDF and save down in a directory of my choosing naming it the contents of a specific cell.

All works fine until I try to copy into a new workbook (I designed in a test workbook as not to corrupt the original)  then I get a

> run time error 1004

and the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("sheet 2")).Select` is highlighted when I debug. Am I missing something simple? as the code works in the original workbook but not in if I paste into a new module in a new workbook?  Sorry i'm quite new to this!

```
sub PrintPDFRT()

Sheets("test").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Sheets("malbru1").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Sheets("sheet 2").Activate
Range("A1:j137").Select

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("sheet 2")).Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="FIle path\" & Range("L7").Value, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is your worksheet named `sheet 2` or `sheet2`? My first guess is the sheet name is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this: (without `Array`)

```
sub PrintPDFRT()

WorkSheets("test").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
WorkSheets("malbru1").Activate
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
WorkSheets("sheet 2").Activate
Range("A1:j137").Select

ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("sheet 2").ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="FIle path\" & Range("L7").Value, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
 End Sub
```